# Apt fails to get sources due compression

Tags: debian, apt

My Debian server (3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64) fails to fetch updates from `security.debian.org`. I think it is caused by repository, because there are only compressed files on the repository. How can I fix it ?

Fetch errors

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.32 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 212.211.132.32 80]
```

Sources setup

```
deb http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.cz.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

Comment: Had the same problem. `sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get update` didn't help. As i remember i removed `securiy` repo, did `apt-get update`, then added it back and `apt-get update` once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed it by comment of Glueon. And it is working fine now.

> Had the same problem. sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get update didn't
>   help. As i remember i removed securiy repo, did apt-get update, then
>   added it back and apt-get update once again.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=766206). A workaround explained in that bug report is to run

```
sudo find /var/lib/apt -type f -exec rm {} \+
sudo apt-get update
```

It worked for me.

Comment: You can just remove the 'partial' folder

`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial`

and then run

`sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding your apt cache:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Then see if it works.